# Get file from the specified path

Tags: java, file-io

I need to read a file from a specified path. E.g: I have a file called abc.txt and it resides inside /dev/user/assets/data/abc.png. 
If one has to read from a Zip file we do something like

```
Zipfile zipFile = new ZipFile("test.zip");
ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry(imagePath); // where image path is /dev/user/assets/data/abc.png.
```

Is there a code something similar to the above for reading from a folder?
Like

```
File folder = new Folder("Users");
```

and give the path "/dev/user/assets/data/abc.png" to the above and read the image.

Comment: A text file which resides inside a .png image file? :S

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `File` has two-args constructor `File(File parent, String child)` that does exactly what you describe (you may just have to throw the leading '/' of the child). Take a look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you want to do. But if what you want to do is simply to read the contents of a file with a given path, then you should'nt use the File API.

Instead you should use a `new FileReader(textFilePath);` or a `new FileInputStream(imageFilePath);`

Look at the following [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html), taken from the java tutorials.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader inputStream = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt"));

            String l;
            while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                outputStream.println(l);
            }
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```